# What are bounded equations?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question for my practice final is "Decide whether the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ described by the equation $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ is bounded or not."

To be honest, I do not know what bounded means in this case so it would be helpful if someone can describe what it means to be bounded.

Comment: "I do not know what bounded means in this case" well, the concept must gave been covered in class -  maybe you should study the material before looking at the practice final?  (There's no such thing as a bounded _equation_, by the way...)

Comment: In general in $R_3$ it means max$|x|,|y|,|z|$ are all finite.

Answer (score 0):

The points $(1,n,n),n=1,2,\cdots$ are all in the solution set. Since this sequence is unbounded, the set of solutions is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

> A subset $S\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ is *bounded* if it is contained in a ball with finite radius; that is, if there exists an $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^3$ and $r\in\mathbb R_{> 0}$ so that for all $\mathbf y\in S$, we have $|\mathbf x-\mathbf y|< r$.

In this question, our set $S$ is given by $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}\subset\mathbb R^3.$$
Now the question is whether we could find an $\mathbb x\in\mathbb R^3$ and $r\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ so that the condition in the definition is fulfilled. Consider what it would mean if the condition were true. For one thing, it would imply that the set cannot have points with infinitely big $z$ values. But, for any $z\in\mathbb R$, the point $(1,z,z)$ always lies in the set! This means that $z$ can actually grow arbitrarily large. Do you see where we get a contradiction here?

---

Here's an image of the required set (generated by *Mathematica*), for $-5\leq x,y\leq 5$. For $S$ to be bounded, we need there to be a ball of finite radius containing this set. Intuitively, you should see easily that this is impossible.

[image]